# MongoDB: restore a collection in the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongorestore

I am trying to import/restore a single collection from within MongoDB (i.e. mongorestore cannot be accessed, I think ...?).

Is it possible? What is the command? Ideally, I'd like to include indexes as well. The backup has been produced by mongodump.

Specifically, I am using the IntelliShell from the excellent MongoChef. I perform other commands in this as well, such as renaming existing collections first.

Comment: `mongorestore` is run from the os shell not the mongo shell. And yes it'll restore the indexes to.

Comment: Thanks ares, I know that (that's what I'm using now), but I was looking for something in the mongo shell (in Javascript).